# IOS Swift App crash when login with facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, crash, facebook-sdk-4.x

I had my iOS app rejected by the Apple review team. They report the app crashes when they Login. When I do testing on my own devices everything works fine.

> full crash log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100138fe8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
8.902161     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183111a18 TCP Conn 0x15fe913a0 SSL Handshake DONE
8.922797     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183111928 TCP Conn 0x15fe913a0 starting SSL negotiation
8.923048     CFNetwork                  0x00000001831b3a30 TCP Conn 0x15fe913a0 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
8.924045     CFNetwork                  0x00000001831b4f5c TCP Conn 0x15fe913a0 event 1. err: 0
14.702718    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018aceeb64 [0x1601cba00] Releasing session
14.765290    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018acee348 [0x1601cba00] Created session
18.109961    CFNetwork                  0x00000001831b3a30 TCP Conn 0x1618cbc30 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
18.110646    CFNetwork                  0x00000001831b4f5c TCP Conn 0x1618cbc30 event 1. err: 0
18.317944    CFNetwork                  0x00000001831b5034 TCP Conn 0x1618cbc30 started



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CC DOUBLE O                     0x0000000100138fe8 LoginViewController.(returnUserData(LoginViewController) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (LoginViewController.swift:228)
1   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x00000001006f68a8 0x1006d0000 + 157864
2   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x00000001006f4594 0x1006d0000 + 148884
3   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x00000001006f4364 0x1006d0000 + 148324
4   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x00000001006f3e18 0x1006d0000 + 146968
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183907990 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 132
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183907800 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 172
7   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x00000001006f3bd4 0x1006d0000 + 146388
8   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x00000001006f30d4 0x1006d0000 + 143572
9   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x00000001006f12a8 0x1006d0000 + 135848
10  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x000000010070a0dc 0x1006d0000 + 237788
11  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x000000010070a034 0x1006d0000 + 237620
12  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x000000010070a4ac 0x1006d0000 + 238764
13  CFNetwork                       0x00000001832a36a8 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 80
14  CFNetwork                       0x00000001832a3638 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 200
15  CFNetwork                       0x00000001832a37ac -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
16  CFNetwork                       0x000000018310f4fc ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 100
17  CFNetwork                       0x00000001831fdb38 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 108
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001990756a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019907e9e4 _dispatch_block_invoke + 540
20  CFNetwork                       0x00000001830fbce4 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 36
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838f46cc CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
22  CFNetwork                       0x00000001830fbbc8 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
23  CFNetwork                       0x00000001830fba88 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312
24  CFNetwork                       0x00000001830fb8b4 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 68
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839c8544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839c7fd8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839c5cd8 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
28  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838f4ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
29  GraphicsServices                0x000000018e988088 GSEventRunModal + 180
30  UIKit                           0x000000018900cffc UIApplicationMain + 204
31  CC DOUBLE O                     0x0000000100100940 main (AppDelegate.swift:19)
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001990a68b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991c44fc kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000199088a04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000199077874 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991c3b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991aa598 write + 8
1   CC DOUBLE O                     0x000000010019f08c CLSSDKFileLog + 444
2   CC DOUBLE O                     0x000000010018e810 CLSMachExceptionServer + 180
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019928bb28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019928ba8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289028 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991a8a40 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991a88bc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839c8108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839c5e0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838f4ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018318db84 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x0000000184953c80 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019928bb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019928ba8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289028 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  GAIThread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991a8a40 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991a88bc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839c8108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839c5e0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838f4ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                      0x000000018486d2bc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   Foundation                      0x00000001848c28f4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   CC DOUBLE O                     0x000000010016d45c +[GAI threadMain:] + 72
8   Foundation                      0x0000000184953c80 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019928bb28 _pthread_body + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019928ba8c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289028 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991c3368 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839ce670 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019928bb28 _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019928ba8c _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289028 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991c3b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991c3b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991c3b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991c3b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001991c3b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199289020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12:

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001618a1441   x1: 0x40000000000000e6   x2: 0x00000001618a1430   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000007   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000000000001   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000ffffffff8   x9: 0x00000000000003b8  x10: 0x000000015ff323a8  x11: 0x0000000000000001
   x12: 0x00000001600b8e10  x13: 0x000001a19fa8fac1  x14: 0x00000000ffffffff  x15: 0x00000000fffffffd
   x16: 0x0000000189976aa1  x17: 0x0000000183913e34  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x400000000000000f
   x20: 0x0000000161872480  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x000000015ff31ff0  x23: 0x0000000161872480
   x24: 0x00000001618a1441  x25: 0x0000000161865c40  x26: 0x000000015fef7fb0  x27: 0x00000001618a1430
   x28: 0x000000010139e3b0  fp: 0x000000016fd36080   lr: 0x0000000100138e38
    sp: 0x000000016fd35f80   pc: 0x0000000100138fe8 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

> line 228 is do self.login("fb", id: self.dict.valueForKey("id") as!
>   String, access: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

```
    func returnUserData()
    {
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dict = result as! NSDictionary
                    print(self.dict)
//                    print(self.dict.objectForKey("email") as! String)
           (line 228) self.login("fb", id: self.dict.valueForKey("id") as! String, access: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
                }
            })
        }
    }

func login(type:String,id:String,access:String){
    self.apiService.requestLogin(type ,id: id, access: access, deviceToken: self.deviceToken, completionHandler: { (obj, success) -> Void in

        self.handlerLoginResponse(obj!)

    })

}


func handlerLoginResponse(obj:AnyObject){
    let json = JSON(obj)
    let status = json["status"].intValue
    let errmessage = json["error"]["message"].stringValue

    switch status {
    case 1:
        let userId = json["data"]["id"].stringValue
        let userToken = json["data"]["token"].stringValue
        self.defaults.setObject(userId, forKey: UserDefaultsContracts.KEY_USER_ID)
        self.defaults.setObject(userToken, forKey: UserDefaultsContracts.KEY_TOKEN)
        self.defaults.synchronize()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToRootView", sender: nil)
    case -5:
        print(errmessage)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CreateAccountViewController", sender: nil)
    default:
        print(errmessage)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include the error message in your question. There should be an error message just before all of the thread stack traces in the crash report.

Comment: And how is this different from the [question you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325660/ios-swift-app-crash-during-app-review-when-click-button) an hour ago?

Comment: i had 2 issue,first is login with Facebook, and previous question is another issue with user click at normal button and crash

Comment: Apparently there isn't any useful error message. But the stack trace indicates your issue is in LoginViewController.swift at line 228. Update your question with the complete method containing that line and point out which line is line 228.

Comment: so i had update code detail above

Comment: Looking at your `login` function, the handler doesn't handle `obj` being nil and since the crash is in the closure that would be my guess.  It seems very risky to force unwrap an object that is returned from a network operation.  At the very least you should check the `success` value and take some appropriate action if it failed, but I would also check `obj` isn't nil.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i'll try this.

Comment: Thank @Paulw11 for your suggestion. this issue solved.